# Update div element value based on cookie in multiple tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I'm inserting and removing div's based on value of cookie. the value of cookie is updated by checking and un-checking the check box. this works fine for a single tab.
but how to update div's in other tab also if multiple tabs are opened for same page. The cookie value is updated as it remains same for browser, but how to add or remove div's with respect to cookie value.

Comment: See [`postMessage()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage)

Comment: Please post code example

Comment: the code is too large to post

Comment: @AdamAzad: postMessage will only work for windows or iframes opened from the same tab, right? it won't work if user writes url of same page in multiple tabs...

Comment: you should use `websocket`

Comment: You can also use local storage...

Comment: i m using cookie so local storage will do no better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a way that worked for me, I used a variable with global scope to store value of cookie. defined a method to check if cookie value is not same as that of variable, refresh the page.

But if you don't need to refresh the current page update the value of variable whenever you update cookie.

So basically i am refreshing other tabs but not my current tab. I know this is not the best way to do this, but it will do the job.

If you find something more efficient please post.

Answer (score 2):

If you're okay with using local storage instead of a cookie, you can use the `storage` event, which fires when a change is made to local storage.

See http://synccheckbox.site44.com/ for a running example. Code pasted below:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>html { font-family:Arial }</style>
</head>
<body>
    This checkbox should synchronize between open tabs:
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" />

    <script>
        function updateCheckbox() {
            document.getElementById('checkbox').checked =
                (localStorage.checked === 'true');
        }
        updateCheckbox();

        document.getElementById('checkbox').addEventListener('change', function () {
            localStorage.checked = this.checked;
        });

        window.addEventListener('storage', function () {
            updateCheckbox();
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can we use local storage in php?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Local storage is a browser feature... it can only be accessed in the browser.

Comment: I think @Pratyush wants to manipulate values taken from local storage into some php variables, and asking for its feasibility

Comment: yes @Anant i m using my cookie in js as well as in php so local storage wont work in my case.

Comment: Okay, so just also write it to a cookie.